# having double value for points

Tags: java, double

Hi
I have a UI which has a panel and you can use your mouse for puting some points on it and it is its code:

```
    double x = evt.getX();
    double y = evt.getY() + 20;
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 10, 10);
    Point point = new Point(x, y);
    pointList.add(point);
```

as you see my "x" field and "y" field has double type but when i print those points ,their value will be int ,how can i keep their value and use them in my functions with double type.
when I print them :

```
[120.0 ,134.0]
[345.0,785.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The positions on the panel are always going to be integers, because that's what getX and getY return. You can't click on half a pixel. ;)

What you have stored *is* actually a double. That's why it says "120.0" rather than just "120". If you store an integer into a floating point type (like a double), then it gets stored as the floating point equivalent of that integer (which is the same as putting ".0" at the end). Because the value you are storing into it will always be an integer, you're always going to end up with a whole number in your doubles (unless you do some other mathematical processing on them which causes them to change)

Comment: You mean that using double type for such these points are useless??

Comment: also in arithmetic operations like minus it will return int type or i.e.,0.23?

Comment: @user472221 , given your example code, having doubles is useless. If you intend to use those values in calculations where rounding problems could be significant, then having doubles is useful.

Comment: In arithmetic operations, the type it returns will be dependent on the particular operators and on the other types in the expression. If you are always using doubles, then you will end up with doubles. If you mix doubles and integers, then automatic type conversion will mean that the end result is a bit more complicated to determine.

Answer (score 8):

Try [java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html)

Answer (score 0):

your double values are being cast back to integers.
short of writing your own toString method (perhaps by extending Point), there is nothing you can do about that.